# Google Fitness API: Accessing from Android Service

Tags: android, google-fit, google-fit-sdk

I have successfully experimented with pulling data from the Sensors API (step count) using the SDK examples. However, when I try to do the same thing from a service, I do not get step count delta callbacks. All the sample code I see always talks about creating the GoogleApiClient using the Activity "this" value and never a service's "this" value. Any idea whether access through a Service is supported?

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented sensor and history api calls from a sticky service. The only thing you need the activity for is the prompt to the user in case connection fails, or sign in is needed. (I think)

So what I have done is that I made classes for the sensor and history functions respectively and then I use local broadcasts, you can probably do it with a bind as well, and then in `onConnectionFail()` I tell the activity that it should prompt the user.

I have other problems with the fit-api but the service part works fine.

Answer (score 0):

It's not difficult, but need a lot of work to do.

Basically, this method "`GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog`" won't work in Service. (That's the real problem. Why not? Who designs this shXt? Totally don't make any sense.)
But if you check again, you will see that there is a method "`startResolutionForResult`" in `ConnectionResult`.
 You can use it to replace "`GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog`".

And ... sorry, that can't solve your problem.

Because you still need an Activity and its method "`onActivityResult`". Even you can get a static Activity,  it still won't work unless you give this Activity a customed "`onActivityResult`" method.

So? Desing an Activity with a customed "`onActivityResult`" method and extend it to all your Activity? ... I am joking.

In my case, I give all my Activity the ability to do a dynamic job in its life cycle. And that's my Activity:

```
public abstract class HTBaseActivity extends FragmentActivity {

public static Activity ACT = null;

public CallByActivityResult callByResult;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ACT = this;

}


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int value1, int value2, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(value1, value2, intent);

    if(callByResult != null){
        callByResult.onActivityResult(value1, value2, intent);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
    ACT = this;
}
```

This Activity was for something else, not "Doing Fitness API in Service." But it truly works.

P.S.
`CallByActivityResult` is an Interface with a method "`onActivityResult(int value1, int value2, Intent intent)`".